# Boosting my own characters?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible to boost one low-level character with my higher-level one if both are on my gamertag? I do not have internet so I cannot join co-op games or anything.

Comment: Can you use splitscreen on the Xbox version?

Comment: Yea I can split screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new profile on your XBox.

1) Play through the campaign (primary player- your profile, secondary player - temporary profile) until you are satisfied with secondary character's level)

2) Create a new character for your profile

3) Start a game using the temporary profile.

4) Join the game split screen with your primary profile and new character.

5) Use the main controller and go kill some high xp stuff.

6) Repeat steps 3 to 5 for each character you want to boost.

Comment: So basically I boost a character on another GT then use _that_ character to boost one on my own GT? Interesting, could work I suppose.

Comment: Yep. I sometimes log my son's profile in on the other controller to get him some experience since he doesn't play as much as I do. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

For PS3 and Xbox:

Join the game as your higher level character, and open the menu. This should allow your second controller to join through split-screen.
(If using the same profile, it will treat your second character as a guest and will not share badass ranks or golden keys)

For PC:
(Requires two monitors, the program "sandboxie" and two controllers)

Steps can be found here (http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=151660)
- TLDR: Sandboxie is a program that will allow you to set splitscreen for BL2 if steam is set to offline

Comment: Will this work since both characters are on the same gamertag?

Comment: Ive never tried it on xbox, but I have heard that splitscreen does work on xbox. I would assume that'd work as well, the same it works on ps3

Comment: Ive noticed people speaking of troubles of playing BL2 on the same PSN profile, but no one complaining about this problem on xbox. There may be no way to play two characters on one gamertag

Comment: I'm just unsure how I would load the second character since the saves go by gamertag.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk If you turn on the 2nd controller but don't sign in, that might allow it to be a guest and gain access to your other characters.

Comment: @Adeese tested this last night. Guests can't save or load anything so this won't work :(

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk no, it doesn't work on Xbox. The second controller can sign in as a different gamertag, or they can sign in as guest, but in either case they can't access the saved character on your gamertag. If you copy the save then the copied character can't get any achievements.

Comment: @keith If i'm not worried about achievements, could I copy the character, boost it, then copy it back to my GT for me to use?

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk I think you can copy a save onto a USB as one tag and back again as another in that case. I'm not sure whether you can isolate the characters from the save though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Since you can only access your own characters when signed in, guests do not have access to them. There is no way to be able to sign in on two controllers so you can only use one of your characters at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just start co-op play with the high-level character as the lead and the low level character as the second player. You'll be able to play and save your second coop profile (at least you can on PS3 and you could in BL1 as well). The gamertag shouldn't matter since you're not playing an online game anyway, both of your characters will receive experience and they should both save, and then you can just load up your "boosted" character solo and they'll still be higher level.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to boost your own ps3 characters. I just did it and started the campaign and lvl 11 in a matter of minutes.